# openfortivpn and ppp issue in ubuntu server

Tags: permissions, vpn, ppp

I'm having trouble implementing this vpn on Ubuntu server.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Particularly I get the error:  pppd: Is not setuid-root and the invoking user is not root.

I have to say that I am using the root user

```
 sudo openfortivpn --trusted-cert 6f0ac15ce35ca1af5e3b751475asdfasdf4ba7a1ec289eda308b95cbf13 xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx.xx:10443 -u 2234 <<< '123' 
VPN account password: 
INFO:   Connected to gateway.
INFO:   Authenticated.
INFO:   Remote gateway has allocated a VPN.
ERROR:  read: Input/output error
INFO:   Cancelling threads...
ERROR:  pppd: Is not setuid-root and the invoking user is not root.
INFO:   Terminated pppd.

INFO:   Closed connection to gateway.
INFO:   Logged out.
```

As you can see below I have ppp installed in the operating system

```
 dpkg -l | grep ppp
ii  ppp                                 2.4.7-2+2ubuntu1.3                amd64        Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP) - daemon
```

and this is in the latest version, I use the apt-get package manager

Instead when I check pppd, I get the following

```
sudo pppd
Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: Operation not permitted
pppd: Sorry - this system lacks PPP kernel support
```

When I try to start or run pppd from the linux kernel I get:

```
modprobe ppp
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.15.0/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ppp not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0


ls -l /lib/modules/4.15.0/modules.builtin.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 17 04:01 /lib/modules/4.15.0/modules.builtin.bin
```

Comment: A good start is to upgrade the OS. 18.04.1 is years behind in updates. An up to date version is 18.04.5

Comment: Thanks.
How can I do it without losing the files on the system?

Comment: On my 18.04 box (kernel 4.15.0-175-generic), PPP kernel support appears to be built in (i.e. `grep PPP /boot/config-$(uname -r)` shows `CONFIG_PPP=y)`. Perhaps the error message is misleading? The openfortivpn message says *ERROR:  pppd: Is not setuid-root* so what actually are its permissions (`ls -l /usr/sbin/pppd`) ?

Comment: (grep PPP /boot/config-$(uname -r)) returns (grep: /boot/config-4.15.0: No such file or directory) and (ls -l /usr/sbin/pppd) returns (-rwsr-xr-- 1 root dip 378600 Jul 23  2020 /usr/sbin/pppd). So pppd is in the system.

Comment: Start by doing an update and upgrade.